# How do I get the ViewContainerRef from the ng-container directive?

Tags: angular

[I follow the guide from the official documentation for loading dynamic components in runtime.](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)

One of the paragraphs says:

> Before adding components, you have to define an anchor point to tell
> Angular where to insert components.

Next, a directive is created.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[adHost]',
})
export class AdDirective {
  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }
}
```

This is necessary in order to get the ViewContainerRef and call the **createComponent()** function;

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-ad-banner',
  template: `
    <div class="ad-banner-example">
      <h3>Advertisements</h3>
      <ng-template adHost></ng-template>
    </div>
  `
})
export class AdBannerComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  
  @ViewChild(AdDirective, {static: true}) adHost!: AdDirective;
  ...
  loadComponent() {
    ...
    viewContainerRef.createComponent<AdComponent>(adItem.component);
    ...
  }
}
```

In the browser it looks like this:

```
<div class="ad-banner-example">
      <h3>Advertisements</h3>
      <ng-component>
        <div class="hero-profile"><h3>Featured Hero Profile</h3><h4>Dr. IQ</h4>
          <p>Smart as they come</p><strong>Hire this hero today!</strong></div>
      </ng-component>
      <!--container-->
 </div>
```

1. Why do we use ng-template? Is it possible to use ng-container instead?
2. In this case, a custom directive is needed only to pull the ViewContainerRef link from ng-template. Is it possible not to create a separate directive for this and pull the ViewContainerRef directly from ng-template using the link #ref and @ViewChild (or something else)?
3. Is the `<!--container-->` comment related to  (which we don't have in the template)?

**UPD:**

I was able to achieve the same effect without using a custom directive.But I'm even more confused. (((

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-ad-banner',
  template: `
    <div class="ad-banner-example">
      <h3>Advertisements xxx</h3>
      <ng-template #insert_slot></ng-template>
    </div>
  `
})
export class AdBannerComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {

  @ViewChild('insert_slot', {read: ViewContainerRef}) adHost!: ViewContainerRef;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.loadComponent();
  }

  loadComponent() {
    ...
    this.adHost.clear();

    const componentRef = this.adHost.createComponent<AdComponent>(adItem.component);
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. No, 2 of them be slightly be the same but not at all (ref: https://dillionmegida.com/p/difference-between-ng-container-and-ng-template/#difference-between-ng-container-and-ng-template)
2. `ViewContainerRef` that inside directive is scope and operate in element's area only. So if you can manage them by create new `Component`  is will be more better and more permanently design.
3. That's behavior of ng-container. Basically, you can think it's that replacement of `<div>` tag, it won't display as `HTML element` but it'll leave the comment to told the content is rendered from `ng-container`. Which still not the case that can be compare with `ng-template`

4 (your UPD). This's still the same. On your `@ViewChild` assigned type is the way to told `Angular` that what's expect that you want it to look down to that target be?

Comment: Fixed issue number 3. StackOverflow took the comment characters to its account.

Comment: Update the answer, wish it can be explain for you to be clear.